# jQuery(...).addClass(...).viewportChecker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Context: I'm using a theme with a lot of custom JS that was all working until I started adding my own javascript, at which point I started getting this error:

```
theme.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).addClass(...).viewportChecker is not a function
```

The line it's erroring on is the following:

```
jQuery('.scroll1').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible  
}); ;
```

At first I assumed jQuery was updating their libraries, but as the issue is still persisting this morning... I do not believe that is the case.

link for assistance is http://yardlad.webbtechgroup.us

Comment: It looks like `viewportChecker` is a jQuery plugin. Are you sure you're referencing it's script file? Also, without a fiddle or, at minimum, enough code to reproduce the problem, there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: I think the issue is related to the scoping of the viewPortChecker function. Chances are it is not apart of the object returned by add class.

Comment: @RichardBarker - it is. Its a jQuery plugin and they are (generally) chainable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You see how your actual jQuery file is loading all the way down there?

That's because it is put after every other javascript include in the head tag. The line

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Should honestly be the first script included. I know you have the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        !window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="rw_common/themes/multiregen/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))
    </script>
```

But, this isn't loading it in the order you need. jQuery should be loaded before any plugins.

You see, these plugins add on to the jQuery object via `jQuery.fn`. But if jQuery hasn't even been loaded yet, what will they add on to? Thin air!

Answer (score -3):

Element with class `scroll1` does not exist on the page you provided. In result, jQuery is unable to find the element on which you're trying to wrap jQuery and then apply functions `addClass` and `viewportChecker`.

Since your functions are chained it seems like the last one is causing the error. Try splitting them and you'll see where actual error location is.